# En que metodo implementar la logica

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación web en `Django`.
Consiste en almacenar las notas finales de las materias de los estudiantes, estoy usando CBV.

```
class StudentScore(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student_info.html'
    notes = ScoreModel.objects.all()
    scores = []

    for score in ScoreModel.objects.all():
        for student in model.objects.all():
            if score.student.pk == student.first_name:
                scores.append(score.score)

    finalnote = float(sum(scores)/20)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['finalnote'] = self.finalnote
        context['scores'] = ScoreModel.objects.all()
        return context
```

Ahí me saca el promedio de todas las notas, entonces quisiera acceder al objeto que me genera la clase `DetailView`.

También estaba pensando en 'filtrarlo' por el `path`, ya que en el `path` recibo tanto la `primary key` como el `first_name` en forma de `slug`.

Quisiera saber como hacer esto usando `CBV` ya que no quiero usar `FBV`.

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con `path` o filtrarlo por `path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Pequeña porción de la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) sobre la vista `DetailView`:**
>
> Mientras esta vista se está ejecutando, `self.object` contendrá el
>   objeto sobre el que está operando la vista.

Entonces para poder acceder al objeto que genera la vista `DetailView`, mejor dicho el objeto sobre el que opera la vista `DetailView`, tendrás que hacerlo atraves de `self.object`, puedes acceder a `self.object` desde cualquier método a excepción del método `get_objetc`.

También seria mejor en mi opinión hacer la gestión y el calculo de las puntuaciones en el mismo método `get_context_data`, de la siguiente manera:

```
class StudentScore(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student_info.html'
    notes = ScoreModel.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        scores = []
        for score in ScoreModel.objects.all():
            for student in model.objects.all():
                if score.student.pk == student.first_name:
                    scores.append(score.score)

        ctx = super().get_context_data()
        ctx['finalnote'] = float(sum(scores)/20)
        ctx['scores'] = ScoreModel.objects.all()

        return ctx
```

Bueno espero haberte ayudado. Por cierto ¿A que te refieres con `path` o filtrarlo por `path`? Para así poder ayudarte.

Comment: Fuciono muchas gracias... me referia a usar los parametros que se pasan en la url. filtrar usando esos parametros pero me parecia muy tedioso entonces queria saber como hacerlo con el objeto que genera la clase Detail Vie.

Comment: Ok, Saludos!!!!